# 'System.ServiceModel.OperationContext' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments

Tags: c#, arguments

In My form

```
 private OperationContext operationContext;


operationContext = new OperationContext();
```

When i debug the code it shows the error

> 'System.ServiceModel.OperationContext' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments

But in my friends form it works fine without any arguments to the  operationContext = new OperationContext();

Comment: Then your friend isn't running the same .NET as you are, or your friend has a different kind of form than you do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe friend use different version of .net framework.
you should see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.operationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I use another form on my machine as different project and it can use     operationContext = new OperationContext(); without any arguments